# Как получить значение элементов добавленных через jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Здравствуйте. Есть код который добавляет на страницу новые элементы:

```
<script>
jQuery('.main').append("<div class='level' id='"+level+"'></div>"); // Добавляю обертку с уровнем

/* Добавляем оберку и подкатегории */
jQuery('.row[data-parent="' + id + '"]').each(function(i) {

    var html     = jQuery(this),
        catID    = html.attr('id'),
        parentID = html.data('parent'),
        el       = html.html();

    jQuery( '.main .level#' + level ).append(
        "<div class='row sub' onclick='ASclick("+catID+")' id='"+catID+"' data-parent='"+parentID+"'>" +
        el +
        "</div>"
    );

});
</script>
```

Работает так как должен.
После добавления мне нужно вытянуть пару значений. Делаю я это так:

```
var lvl   = jQuery('body .sub#' + id ).parent();
```

Но консоль говорит мне что такого элемента в ДОМЕ нет.

Есть какое-то решение ? Заранее благодарен всем кто откликнется.

HTML:

```
<div class="main">

    <div class="level" id="0"><div class="row" onclick="ASclick(57)" id="57" data-parent="55">
                    <div class="column" id="57" data-parent="55">

                        <div class="name">Чемоданы</div>
                        <img class="image" src="http://www.ljplus.ru/img4/w/w/www34/DSCF2093.jpg">

                    </div>
                  </div><div class="row" onclick="ASclick(56)" id="56" data-parent="55">
                    <div class="column" id="56" data-parent="55">

                        <div class="name">Лодки</div>
                        <img class="image" src="http://www.ljplus.ru/img4/w/w/www34/DSCF2093.jpg">

                    </div>
                  </div><div class="row" onclick="ASclick(58)" id="58" data-parent="55">
                    <div class="column" id="58" data-parent="55">

                        <div class="name">Лифоны</div>
                        <img class="image" src="http://www.ljplus.ru/img4/w/w/www34/DSCF2093.jpg">

                    </div>
                  </div><div class="row" style="display: none;" onclick="ASclick(61)" id="61" data-parent="58">
                    <div class="column activeCat" id="61" data-parent="58">

                        <div class="name">Шанель</div>
                        <img class="image" src="http://www.ljplus.ru/img4/w/w/www34/DSCF2093.jpg">

                    </div>
                  </div><div class="row" style="display: none;" onclick="ASclick(63)" id="63" data-parent="61">
                    <div class="column" id="63" data-parent="61">

                        <div class="name">Розовый</div>
                        <img class="image" src="http://www.ljplus.ru/img4/w/w/www34/DSCF2093.jpg">

                    </div>
                  </div><div class="row" style="display: none;" onclick="ASclick(62)" id="62" data-parent="61">
                    <div class="column" id="62" data-parent="61">

                        <div class="name">Красный</div>
                        <img class="image" src="http://www.ljplus.ru/img4/w/w/www34/DSCF2093.jpg">

                    </div>
                  </div><div class="row" style="display: none;" onclick="ASclick(60)" id="60" data-parent="58">
                    <div class="column" id="60" data-parent="58">

                        <div class="name">Луи Ви Тон</div>
                        <img class="image" src="http://www.ljplus.ru/img4/w/w/www34/DSCF2093.jpg">

                    </div>
                  </div><div class="row" style="display: none;" onclick="ASclick(64)" id="64" data-parent="60">
                    <div class="column" id="64" data-parent="60">

                        <div class="name">Серый</div>
                        <img class="image" src="http://www.ljplus.ru/img4/w/w/www34/DSCF2093.jpg">

                    </div>
                  </div><div class="row" style="display: none;" onclick="ASclick(59)" id="59" data-parent="58">
                    <div class="column" id="59" data-parent="58">

                        <div class="name">Дольче Га Банна</div>
                        <img class="image" src="http://www.ljplus.ru/img4/w/w/www34/DSCF2093.jpg">

                    </div>
                  </div><div class="row" style="display: none;" onclick="ASclick(65)" id="65" data-parent="59">
                    <div class="column" id="65" data-parent="59">

                        <div class="name">Черный</div>
                        <img class="image" src="http://www.ljplus.ru/img4/w/w/www34/DSCF2093.jpg">

                    </div>
                  </div></div>  <div class="level" id="1"><div class="row" onclick="ASclick(61)" id="61" data-parent="58">
                    <div class="column activeCat" id="61" data-parent="58">

                        <div class="name">Шанель</div>
                        <img class="image" src="http://www.ljplus.ru/img4/w/w/www34/DSCF2093.jpg">

                    </div>
                  </div><div class="row" onclick="ASclick(60)" id="60" data-parent="58">
                    <div class="column" id="60" data-parent="58">

                        <div class="name">Луи Ви Тон</div>
                        <img class="image" src="http://www.ljplus.ru/img4/w/w/www34/DSCF2093.jpg">

                    </div>
                  </div><div class="row" onclick="ASclick(59)" id="59" data-parent="58">
                    <div class="column" id="59" data-parent="58">

                        <div class="name">Дольче Га Банна</div>
                        <img class="image" src="http://www.ljplus.ru/img4/w/w/www34/DSCF2093.jpg">

                    </div>
                  </div></div><div class="level" id="2"><div class="row" onclick="ASclick(63)" id="63" data-parent="61">
                    <div class="column" id="63" data-parent="61">

                        <div class="name">Розовый</div>
                        <img class="image" src="http://www.ljplus.ru/img4/w/w/www34/DSCF2093.jpg">

                    </div>
                  </div><div class="row" onclick="ASclick(62)" id="62" data-parent="61">
                    <div class="column" id="62" data-parent="61">

                        <div class="name">Красный</div>
                        <img class="image" src="http://www.ljplus.ru/img4/w/w/www34/DSCF2093.jpg">

                    </div>
                  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста html представление дома, который будет результатом работы скрипта.

Comment: @Arnial Добавил

Comment: что такое level и id, откуда они берутся

Comment: @L.Vadim уровень вложенности категории, айди категории в базе.

Comment: @SlavikOkara откуда эти переменные берутся - где объявляются, назначаются - в Вашем коде

Comment: Вот полный код: http://codepad.org/VHmmtXuL

Comment: @SlavikOkara "консоль говорит ... такого элемента нет." - как она Вам это говорит? Создайте работающий пример, воспроизводящий проблему с помощью кнопки "Фрагмент кода на ..." в редакторе вопроса.

Comment: @Igor Изначально у меня по одному элементу в доме. Потом скриптом я дублирую и вывожу еще один. В доме их уже 2, а `jQuery('.row#61').size()` выводит только 1 (первый)

Comment: @SlavikOkara у Вас в DOM-е создаются элементы с повторяющимися `id` - это противоречит спецификации html и работать не будет.

Comment: @Igor Как же мне тогда поступить ?

Comment: @SlavikOkara всё правильно. На странице не может быть 2х элементов с одинаковыми id. Поэтому браузеры и jquery берут первый попавшийся элемент с нужным id. И затем проверяют его на соответствие вашей выборке.

Comment: @SlavikOkara используйте `class` вместо `id`

Comment: @Igor Сейчас попробую

Comment: @Arnial Сейчас попробую

Comment: @Igor Получилось, спасибо !

Comment: @Arnial Получилось, спасибо !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена заменой атрибута id на data-id.

Comment: реально решена??? а разве тут не нужно делегировать?